# Why is Transaction Value showing 0 ETH on Etherscan?

Tags: blockchain, ether, gas, etherscan, evm

I'm not sure why the transaction value on Etherscan is showing as 0 ETH when the transaction was confirmed.

According to the recipient, they haven't received anything in their wallet either and I'm not sure what's gone wrong as their wallet address is correct.

You can view the transaction [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6995f9871aa7906450a9ba57294abc67ad22ca9824f77147c418061e62e3e469).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using [Coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/), the initial transaction you made didn't really contain the ETH, but instead, it made a contract call that triggered the actual transaction to send the ETH from Coinbase's smart contract to the recipient.

By looking at the internal transactions, you can see the ETH actually being sent.

[image]

The final `Transfer` in the list goes to address `0x52fe1Cc40B2497f3649ec2526e6F1D5af7158855`, which is the `to` in your transaction.

You sent the user **0.11915635** ETH and paid a gas fee of **0.00336** ETH.

If you subtract the amount sent by the amount paid as a fee, you get **.11882035**.

And if we check the amount of ETH that was transferred to the recipient:

[image]

You can see the values match, so you did correctly send the ETH. If the recipient claims their balance hasn't been incremented yet, then it probably is caused by the delay Coinbase has implemented, likely to prevent AML/theft.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a transfer transaction. Rather, the transaction is the execution of a function of the smart contract. After executing this function of the smart contract, a number of internal transfer transactions are executed, which can be seen in the link below, internal transactions and their amount.
[link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6995f9871aa7906450a9ba57294abc67ad22ca9824f77147c418061e62e3e469#internal)